# Want to find the url from html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given below is the html of a web page:

```
<div id="website-view">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a target="_blank" href="/redir/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook%2Ecom%2Fshwet&amp;urlhash=GvM1">My Facebook</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to fetch the url here from the anchor tag given in href using javscript or jquery also i want to parse the url here correctly ie: url here is  http://facebook.com/shwet by removing the % and other symbols.

Comment: And how's that working out?

Comment: can i see the code how you did?

Comment: this is the code i get from inspect element of an html page.........how's that working out means?

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra, it means we expect you to show reasonable effort at solving this problem. At the very least, post the code you have tried and explain the problems you're encountering with it.

Comment: var website = document.querySelector('#website-view ul li a ').innerHTML . But it is wrong as i want the href url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```js
$(function() {
  var a_href = $('#website-view a').attr('href');
  var decodedUri = decodeURIComponent(a_href);
  var url = decodedUri.split("url=")[1].split("&")[0];
  alert(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="website-view">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="/redir/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook%2Ecom%2Fshwet&amp;urlhash=GvM1">My Facebook</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it is also showing &urlhash=GvM1 along with answer. so split() is required

Answer (score 1):

You can use  :

1) `$('#website-view a').attr('href')` to get the href value

2) `.decodeURI()` the fetched URL.

3) split on occurence of `url=`

4) get the second returned object using `[1]`

```
decodeURI($('#website-view a').attr('href')).split("url=")[1]
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6vu3ux0/)**

Comment: it is also showing &urlhash=GvM1 along with answer.so i suppose i have to split the value returned

Comment: [unescape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) is deprecated

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra: you can do that.